# How can I modify (not remove!) duplicated elements in a Python list, while preserving their order?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list:

`L = [0.8963, 0.8963, 0.1234, 0.3456, 0.3456, 0.3456, 0.6789]`

and would want to modify only duplicated values, leaving the first one untouched and adding each time a float (e.g., 0.0001) to the remaining duplicates.

I tried this code:

```
def modify_duplicates_ordered(L):
    L_mod = []
    dupl = set([x for x in L if L.count(x) > 1])
    print 'dupl', dupl
    for j in L:
        if j in list(dupl) and not L_mod:
            L_mod.append(j)
        elif j in list(dupl) and L_mod:
            j += float(0.0001)
            L_mod.append(j)
        else:
            L_mod.append(j)
    return L_mod



L_mod = modify_duplicates_ordered(L)  
print 'L_mod', L_mod
```

and the output is:

```
dupl set([0.8963, 0.3456])  
L_mod [0.8963, 0.8964, 0.1234, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.3457, 0.6789]
```

The 'ideal' output should be:

`L_mod [0.8963, 0.8964, 0.1234, 0.3457, 0.3458, 0.3459, 0.6789]`

I cannot figure out how to modify the other duplicated values (here 0.3457): I've found a ton of code to remove duplicated values in a Python list (also using enumerate() function), but without success.

Comment: If you have a list [0.001,0.001,0.001,0.002] you want to end up with [0.001,0.002,0.003,0.002] or [0.001,0.003,0.004,0.002] or [0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004]?

Comment: Thank u Raviteja for editing, I'm new in Stackoverflow...  @hashemi: one of the last two solutions is the same, the important is to have different values at the fourth decimal for all duplicates within the list, leaving the first three decimals untouched (that's the meaning of adding 0.0001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways:

```
def modify_duplicates_ordered(original):
    result = []
    for val in original:
        while val in result:
                val += 0.0001
        result.append(val)
```

Comment: Thank you Max! I tried and it works fine for me, even for len(L)=10000 or more, full of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

there are two problems here 
how large is your list and how much time will you allocate for this task ?
and precision problems

1. do you want an O(n^3) ,O(n^2) , O(n log n) , O(n) solution ?
2. your list contains floating points that poses the problem of how can we determine if two numbers are actually equal (for example if one element is the output of 0.9 - 0.8 and the other is 0.1 logically/Mathematically they are equal but practically 0.9 - 0.8 = 0.09999999999999998 (python 2.7 ,64-bits ) - usually to compare to two floating point numbers x and y we say that they are equal if abs(x - y) < eps (where eps is a small number chosen for the particular application )
3. other posted solutions fail the case where there are many duplicates of the same element for example if there are a 1001 duplicates of x then you expect that the 1000th occurrence should get 0.1 to be added to it .. however other posted solutions so far will add 0.10000000000000184 (on 64-bit platform)

here is my O(n) -numerically stable - solution assuming that two numbers are equal if and only if they have the same representation

```
def modify_duplicates_ordered(original):
    D = {}
    result = [];
    for value in original: D[value] = 0;
    for value in original: 
        result.append(value + D[value] * 0.0001);
        D[value] += 1;
    return result;
```

Comment: Thank you Noureldin for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
def modify_duplicates_ordered(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L
    for ind in range(0,len(L[1:])):
        while L[ind] in L[:ind]:
            L[ind] += 0.0001
    return L
```

This modifies the original list, if you don't want that, you can just copy L in the beginning and work on the copy instead

Comment: Thank u Cantfindname for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
>>> L = [0.8963, 0.8963, 0.1234, 0.3456, 0.3456, 0.3456, 0.6789]
>>> for i in range(len(L)):
...     current = L.pop(i)
...     while True:
...         try: dup_idx = L.index(current)
...         except ValueError: break
...         L[dup_idx] += .0001
...     L.insert(i, current)
...     
>>> 
>>> L
[0.8963, 0.8964, 0.1234, 0.3456, 0.3457, 0.3458, 0.6789]
```

I iter through the list, pop out the current value, search duplicate and increment them, put back the current value in array, then goes to the next element.

Comment: Thank u Cyrbil, your explanation is very clear! I cannot upvote it because I haven't still a 15 reputation score...

Answer (score 0):

You must care for the case when adding `0.0001` to a duplicate give a value already in the list.

You could do:

```
def modify_duplicates_ordered(L):
    delta = float(0.0001) # why not simply 0.0001 ?
    L_mod = []
    unique_vals = set()
    for j in L:
        while j in unique_vals:
            j += delta
        unique_vals.add(j)
        L_mod.append(j)
    return L_mod
```

Or if you prefere to modify the list in place (this version returns `None`):

```
def modify_duplicates_ordered_inplace(L):
    delta = float(0.0001) # why not simply 0.0001 ?
    unique_vals = set()
    for ix, j in enumerate(L):
        if j in unique_vals: # this test only avoids rewriting same value
            while j in unique_vals:
                j += delta
            L[ix] = j
        unique_vals.add(j)
```

Both routines give `[0.8963, 0.8964, 0.1234, 0.3456, 0.3457, 0.3458, 0.6789]` as result.

For the example given by @hashemi in comment (`[0.001,0.001,0.001,0.002]`), those methods give `[0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004]`

Comment: Thank you Serge for your answer, it would be useful!